# order by most tags in a set

Tags: mysql, sql-server

```
SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT  Username, TimesUsed FROM  UserInfo " +
           "WHERE  (Category IN ( " + query + ")) " + "ORDER BY TimesUsed DESC", conn);
```

where query = 'css','php','html' for e.g.

i want to order them in such a way that the users that have the most tags in query, are placed on top.

at the moment they are ordered according to the number of times they used a particular tag of the set.

any ideas? thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand, you need the total of all tags used, and `TimesUsed` relates to specific tags.  If that's correct, then you can `SUM(TimesUsed)` and `GROUP BY Username`

```
SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT  Username, SUM(TimesUsed) AS TotalUsed FROM  UserInfo " +
       "WHERE  (Category IN ( " + query + ")) " + "GROUP BY Username ORDER BY SUM(TimesUsed) DESC", conn);
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", query);
```

Your complete SQL:

```
SELECT
  Username, 
  SUM(TimesUsed) AS TotalUsed
FROM  UserInfo
WHERE Category IN ('php','css','sql','etc')
GROUP BY Username
ORDER BY SUM(TimesUsed) DESC
```